# Shutter shows a broken icon on Ubuntu Mate 20.04

Tags: icons, gtk, mime-type, shutter

An issue has been reported about a GTK app (Shutter) not showing a tray icon on Ubuntu Mate 20.04 with some icon themes (most probably those which don't provide a corresponding icon themselves so the default one needs to be used): https://github.com/shutter-project/shutter/issues/363

We could find the following error in the terminal output:

```
(shutter:2807): Gtk-WARNING **: 21:55:32.455: Could not load a pixbuf from icon theme.
This may indicate that pixbuf loaders or the mime database could not be found.
```

We tried:

- Reinstalling `libgdk-pixbuf-2.0-0` and `shared-mime-info` as proposed in https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=223801.
- Running `update-mime-database /usr/share/mime` and `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders --update-cache` as well as `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders --update-cache` as proposed at https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=261143 and also made sure that the permissions of `/usr/share/mime` are 755 and `/usr/share/mime/icons` are 644.

Still, the icon isn't shown. I cannot reproduce the issue, neither on my Arch and Manjaro machines nor on any of my Ubuntu VMs (Ubuntu Mate 20.04, Ubuntu Gnome 20.04 and 21.04).

I'm out of ideas now, any help in troubleshooting is appreciated!

Comment: It may not be the same issue but [this recent Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1350900/shutter-icon-in-system-tray-ubuntu-20-04-2-lts/1351739#1351739) may hold some clues.

Comment: Thanks, that's indeed a different issue when no icon is shown at all, while here a missing icon symbol is shown (see also screenshot in the linked github issue).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is solved by running

```
update-icon-caches /usr/share/icons/*
```

Comment: Do you need a `sudo` with that?

Comment: Yes, as it writes into `/usr/`.